# timezoneinfo hosted linux is wrong of the daylightsavingtimestart in .net core

Tags: asp.net, c, .net

i want to get a DaylightTransitionStart and DaylightTransitionEnd by GetAdjustmentRules method of TimeZoneInfo in .net core,that is hosted windows server is correct like of year 2020 dst is 03/08 2020 02:00:00 to 11/01 2020 02:00:00, but that hosted linux is wrong, i got a 11/03 2020 01:00:00 to 03/08 2020 01:59:59, this is standard time of 2019-2020, this is a bug? or i need to do anything to correct it?

Comment: Please provide the code you're using, or any attempt to assist will be a guess.

Comment: For which time zone you are observing the unexpected results? Also, could you please format you dates in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format? (Or alternatively state the format/locale you are using)